# How to stop command prompt from closing in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am very new to python.. I used the code

```
x = input(" Hey what is your name " )       
print(" Hey, " + x)  
input(" press close to exit ")
```

Because i have looked for this problem on internet and came to know that you have to put some dummy input line at the end to stop the command prompt from getting closed but m still facing the problem.. pls Help

I am using python 3.3

Comment: you can either run the script through pythons idle platform, so it wont 'close' or you can open a command line (cmd) and then run your script from there, it wont 'close'

Comment: I'm not sure what you're looking for.  does `python -i script.py` do what you want?  What command prompt is closing?  The python command prompt or the shell that you're running python through?

Comment: hum, i think i know the problem: are you giving an input after the second "input" statement? the purpose of the input command is to hang ("stay there and not close") untill the user presses a key. if you give an input, it's closing.

Comment: No i am giving the first input then second line i am asking for python to print it.. then i m asking again python for an input so that it stays there.. It works perfect on idle but not on cmd

Answer (score 24, accepted):

On windows, it's the CMD console that closes, because the Python process exists at the end.

To prevent this, open the console first, then use the command line to run your script. Do this by right-clicking on the folder that contains the script, select `Open console here` and typing in `python scriptname.py` in the console.

The alternative is, as you've found out, to *postpone* the script ending by adding a `input()` call at the end. This allows the user of the script to choose when the script ends and the console closes.

Comment: Note that you (at least on Windows 7) need to shift + right-click on the directory containing your source files, not the script itself.

Comment: Ya i tried that too but still the command prompt closed instantly even after adding an input

Comment: @user1946082: Sounds like you created an error in your script instead. An `input()` call, by itself, does not just exit Python without input.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I am getting really confused why isn't it working would you mind to help me via teamviewer

Comment: @Tim, Martijn: No need to shift+right-click, just right-click alone will bring up the context menu.

Comment: To see "Open console here", yes. On the script itself a different context menu will be displayed. On my system one of the items is "Open with" that has a submenu with "Python" on it. When I run that though, the window closes after I respond to the first `input`.

Comment: @martineau: but that option will open a console that'll close again when the script exits, which is what we want to avoid here. :-)

Comment: True, but why doesn't the second `input` make it wait like the first one?

Comment: @martineau: It still waits. Unless the OP caused an exception at that point by making a mistake..

Comment: Well, it doesn't wait on my system, like the OP's, either. There is no exception as far as I can see.

Comment: @martineau: and that happens when you run it in the console from `python scriptname.py` too? Does it exit when it is supposed to ask for input?

Comment: Ok, now I get a `NameError: name 'martineau' is not defined` on the `x = input(" Hey what is your name " )`. Wasn't seeing this earlier for some reason, but am now. Doesn't happen if I type `"martineau"` and press Enter. Looks line `input` is trying to `eval` what I type in.

Comment: @martineau: Use python 3 instead of 2, or use `raw_input()`.

Comment: Oops, thought I was via `#!/usr/bin/env python3` and pylauncher.

Comment: Tried it, but it doesn't run:

>>> python C:\Users\Steve\Downloads\fast-wavenet-master\fast-wavenet-master\wavenet\models.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python C:\Users\Steve\Downloads\fast-wavenet-master\fast-wavenet-master\wavenet\models.py
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @Hatchling: you are trying to execute the command *inside Python itself*. You need to open a *CMD window*, not Python.

Answer (score 16):

That can be done with os module. Following is the simple code :

```
import os
os.system("pause")
```

This will generate a pause and will ask user to press any key to continue.

[edit: The above method works well for windows os. It seems to give problem with mac (as pointed by ihue, in comments). The thing is that "os" library is operating system specific and some commands might not work with one operating system like they work in another one.]

Comment: "os" library is operating system specific. I am using this with windows and it works just fine because there's actually a "pause" command in cmd. Maybe, linux has some other way of achieving this.

Comment: All right, Thanks for your clarification. I'll check out how to do this specifically on a Mac, but you should have mentioned that as part of your answer.

Comment: True ihue, I added that. Thanks for raising this. Please share your findings, as well, for mac.

Answer (score 3):

For Windows Environments:

If you don't want to go to the command prompt (or work in an environment where command prompt is restricted), I think the following solution is gooThe solution I use is to create a bat file.

Use notepad to create a text file. In the file the contents will look something like:

`my_python_program.py
pause`

Then save the file as "my_python_program.bat" - DO NOT FORGET TO SELECT "All Files!

When you run the bat file it will run the python program and pause at the end to allow you to read the output. Then if you press any key it will close the window.

Answer (score 2):

Just Add Simple input At The End Of Your Program it Worked For Me

```
input()
```

Try it And It Will Work Correctly

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
import sys

status='idlelib' in sys.modules

# Put this segment at the end of code
if status==False:
    input()
```

This will only stop console window, not the IDLE.