# python program crashes on error

Tags: python, python-3.2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to stop command prompt from closing in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142509/how-to-stop-command-prompt-from-closing-in-python)

I am doing some basic scripting, and it appears that when the program encounters an error, it just exits.

Lets say I do `print()` wrong; instead of debugging and displaying error upon execution, it just exits.

How do I stop that?

Comment: That's not Python doing that, that's the windows console window.

Comment: it is something like that Martijn, however there was no solution attached to that link. Plus, my issue has nothing to do with the input as OP in that link is working on.

Comment: The solution is in my answer: open up the console, then run your python script from the command line. The `input()` problem is not the real issue there, it's the fact that the window closes early and thus doesn't show the error that the question asker made.

Comment: Ok, your answer is correct. For those finding this article:  To execute on windows, I put python in my variable path (set path=%path%;C:\python32), then executed from command line, as Martijn stated. Now it is working as expected.

Comment: how do I accept your answer?

Comment: You can't. Only the original question asker can mark that answer as accepted, I am afraid. With a little more reputation (15 or more) you can vote on that answers instead.

Comment: Ok no problem. Thanks. I searched the wrong terms when trying to research my problem. If I would have search - command or script closes when executing python, then that would have showed up, instead of my new question.

Comment: No problem; now anyone using your search terms will find the other question too. Thanks for making it easier for people to find answers! :-)