# Importing a txt into a dictionary causes python to crash?

Tags: python, dictionary, crash

I've followed the first answer on this thread:

[Python - file to dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4803999/python-file-to-dictionary)

And whenever I try and run the script, Python just closes. everything, even my other scripts I'm not working on.

Here's what I've got written, its virtually the same:

```
    d = {}
with open("C:\Users\Owatch\Documents\Python\FunStuff\nsed.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        (key, val) = line.split()
        d[int(key)] = val

print(d)
```

The only thing I changed was the file location as that's what I understood I was to include to fix the error about not finding the file

Elaboration:

Here is the code I am supposed to use:

```
d = {}
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
       (key, val) = line.split()
       d[int(key)] = val
```

Here is what I did, adding a file path in place of file.txt, and having it so that it would or should print the dictionary d as soon as it's done.

```
d = {}
with open("C:\Users\Owatch\Documents\Python\Unisung Net Send\nsed.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        (key, val) = line.split()
        d[int(key)] = val

print(d)
```

The problem is I cannot even run this, as Python just crashes, I am running version:  3.1

Comment: can you please elaborate. Looking at your code, it seems that you have an indentation error.

Comment: Are you running this on Windows? If so, by 'just crashing' you mean the command window closes again?

Comment: See [How to stop command prompt from closing in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142509/14142564#14142564) if that is the case.

Comment: And last but not least, does your input have one space per line, or more?

Comment: Just a wold guess. The full file path contains \n. in the file name: nsed.txt. Try using os.path.join

Comment: What I mean is that when I try and run it in IDLE, it simply crashes. I am not using the command prompt. My text file looks like this: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BwYE5uc9NjE-cEo2VzIzb0IzdmM/edit?usp=sharing         And I am not sure what you mean about the file path GodMan   (I am running this on Windows 7)

Comment: You should probably make that file public. Try using http://gist.github.com/

Comment: @GodMan Could you explain what you mean with the file path?

Comment: I think the answer below by 'Martijn Pieters' explains that

Comment: When you say 'crash' in that case you most probably mean there is a traceback. Next time, please include that traceback in your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
open("C:\Users\Owatch\Documents\Python\FunStuff\nsed.txt")
```

to

```
open(r"C:\Users\Owatch\Documents\Python\FunStuff\nsed.txt")
```

Otherwise "\nsed" will be taken as a newline plus "sed".

Update:

From your input file, problem is:

```
d[int(key)] = val
```

Because your first column are letters, not integers. Change it to:

```
d[key] = val
```

Or: (if you prefer number keys)

```
d[ord(key) - ord('a')] = val
```

Comment: I got this error:   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owatch\Documents\Python\FunStuff\File Import", line 5, in <module>
    d[int(key)] = val
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'

Comment: Fixed. Thank you, if you could help me a little more and explain exactly what is going on please? I hate it when I don't understand what is being undertaken. IF you don't want to, its all cool. I am probably asking a little much. Thanks for solving the problem

Comment: No problem. `int(x)` converts a string or number `x` to an integer. Since your first column are all letters, it fails to do so. If you don't care the numbers, just remove `int`. If you prefer number keys, `ord` will give you integer ordinal of a letter, and `ord(key) - ord('a')` will give you the index starting from letter 'a'.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `r''` raw string literal to prevent Python from interpreting `\n` as a newline:

```
with open(r"C:\Users\Owatch\Documents\Python\Unisung Net Send\nsed.txt") as f:
```

or use double backslashes:

```
with open("C:\\Users\\Owatch\\Documents\\Python\\Unisung Net Send\\nsed.txt") as f:
```

or forward slashes instead:

```
with open(r"C:/Users/Owatch/Documents/Python/Unisung Net Send/nsed.txt") as f:
```

All three versions are valid on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Change d[int(key)] to d[ord(key)]

Comment: What is the difference from using d[ord(key)]  from using d[key] = val

Comment: And what if I want my second column to be numbers, and not numbers in ' ' ?

Comment: ord('a') gives you 97. This 97 will be considered by the hashing function inside python's dictionary d, so it can act as a key

Comment: d[key] directly takes python's help to provide 'a' to the hashing function, so that 'a' acts as the key. So, while referring to the value given to the ley 'a' in this case, you will use d['a'].
In the other case, you will use d[ord('a')] or d[97]

Comment: Referring to the answer by 'Hui ZHeng', d[ord(key) - ord('a')] = val means that d[0] is called for 'a', d[1] for 'b' and similarly d[25] for 'z'

Comment: @Owatch: The second column in your file is a float number in string form. So, as an answer to your question regarding second column as numbers, you might want to use float(val) instead of just val.
Alos, it would only matter when you are calculating something with them, but, for the dictionary d, it doesnt matter