# Why Python/Selenium script only works from a pre-opened console?

Tags: python, selenium

I have written a script using Python and Selenium library for some of my web-automation tasks.
When I open CMD and execute "python myscript.py" (without the quotes), It does the job flawlessly.
But When I double click on "myscript.py" to run it, It opens the driver console window (can't see the console window of my own script there) and navigates to my prefered webpage using the browser but does nothing after that.
By the way, I'm using "IEDriverServer.exe" which has a console window itself.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49146/how-can-i-make-an-exe-file-from-a-python-program Your python is not executable without saying it's a python file your machine can't figure that out

Comment: Your question isn't really python related. All CMD scripts open a window, then exit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop command prompt from closing in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14142509/how-to-stop-command-prompt-from-closing-in-python)